# How to automatically backup large amounts of data from AWS S3 to Microsoft Azure

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-storage

We are using AWS S3 to store and server our content. We would like to make a backup of that data to Microsoft Azure Archive storage. I have tried to find a tutorial on how we can achieve this but some answers I found linked to expired resources.

We already have over 30 TB of storage and we are increasing it with about 1 TB every few days, with the possibility to go over 1 TB per day in the future.

How can we automate data replication from S3 to Azure at this kind of scale?

Comment: Mircea , could you please mark as answer if it was helpful for you ? this will make it relevant to all the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways: to transfer data from S3 to Azure storage: using Azure data factory, full documentation can be found here: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service**

*"Supported capabilities
You can copy data Amazon S3 to any supported sink data store. For a list of data stores that are supported as sources or sinks by the copy activity, see the Supported data stores table.
Specifically, this Amazon S3 connector supports copying files as-is or parsing files with the supported file formats and compression codecs."*

Or you can use AzureCopy: **https://github.com/kpfaulkner/azurecopy**  (Not a Microsoft product)
Since you mentioned it’s a large amount of data, the first option might be the best. 
You may also have to manually switch the access tier to archiving upon the transfer.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try using the Azure Data Factory connector to S3.